# Regex handle multiple "key=value" pairs in random order

Tags: regex, go

I have a message contains header and payload for example "header payload_key1=value1 payloadkey2=value2". The header varies based on specific protocol and the payload in `key=value` pattern but the keys can be in any order, therefore I prefer using regex other than split based on delimiter. I am using the below regex to parse the ordered string, can anyone help how to write a regex that can handle random order key value pairs like `datetime, event and duration` in different orders?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt";
    "regexp"
)

// code from stackoverflow
func groupmap(s string, r *regexp.Regexp) map[string]string {
values := r.FindStringSubmatch(s)
keys := r.SubexpNames()

// create map
d := make(map[string]string)
for i := 1; i < len(keys); i++ {
    d[keys[i]] = values[i]
}

    return d
}

func main() {
    input := `extra_data_probably_has_equal_sign_in_it datetime="2021-05-30T11:02:00-09:00" level=info event="event content" duration=0`
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`datetime="(?P<datetime>.*?)"\sevent=(?P<event>.*?)\s\sduration=(?P<duration>.*?)\s`)
    fmt.Println(groupmap(s, re))
}
```

Comment: Take it in two parts. First, split the string into `key=value` pairs. Then split each pair on the first `=`. The parsing is complicated because you have quoted values which contain whitespace.

Comment: Hi @Schwern. In my message it contains 2 parts: header and payload. The key value pair is in payload, if use split, I have to separate the header with payload first.

Comment: Do you want to extract the value for each key, or verify that all key=value pairs are present?

Comment: Extract the key and value pairs with specify key name in regex then if there's extra key value pairs I don't worry about it

Comment: @HaifengZhang Simplify it by doing one step at a time. Write a regex to strip off the header. Then split it into a list of `key=value` pairs. Then split each pair on `=` and stick them into a map. Can the values have escaped quotes? `key="val\"ue"`?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to split on spaces, but only those not inside quotes, via this regex:

```
` +(?=(?:(?:[^"]*"){2})*[^"]*$)`
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/CcdxHO0tWNIAFf).

This works by requiring an *even* number of quotes after the space.

To also handle escaped quotes, eg

```
key="foo \"quoted text\" bar"
```

Use this regex:

```
 +(?=(?:(?:(?:\\"|[^"])*(?<!\\)"){2})*(?:\\"|[^"])*$)
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/24K91GLKu1l4LU).

Comment: Does this handle escaped quotes?

Comment: @Schwern Answer now includes an “escape proof” regex.